# Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_165_0.MYI'; try to repair it

Tags: mysql

i just check my whm it was showing heavy load on server i clicked on load then  i found that mysql was throwing heavy load on server . i just checked mysql error log was which was showing this error several times and i checked my tmp folder it has 4 gb of ram but i found that error size was bigger than 4 gb however tmp will show that it has used only 12% of available memory can anyone tell how to know the query from this code which is causing heavy load on server

here is error

```
   130210  0:02:12 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_165_0.MYI'; try to repair it
```

want to know the query and how much memory it is consuming

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I have it too.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the temp tables are overflowing the assigned filesystem space.

```
ubuntu@server:/vol/mysql$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       8256952 7837084       440 100% /
```